# How to use an image as the base of a SceneView in ArcGIS for JS 4.x

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

In SceneView I want to add an image as the base image what do I do?

It looks like this picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [MediaLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-MediaLayer.html) pointing to the URL of your image, then set that as the base layer in your map.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this is my first question, I did not expect to be answered so quickly. After testing, it has achieved the effect I want. However, MediaLayer was only released in v4.24, and I used v4.21 in my project, so it is a pity that it cannot be used in the project.